Is it possible for an object or expression evaluating to itself when negated?
As I stated in my previous post (can true ever be false?), I'm from a programming background, so please forgive me for asking programming-related logic questions. Now, here is my question: Given an arbitrary object, expression or statement X, is it possible for any X to logically exists such that
X = ~X

or, in the syntax of the programming language Python,
X == not X

? Is this even possible? I though up of various examples, but the negation of all of them always result in the opposite value of the X itself. Some examples:
X = 0
~X -> true, thus does not equal `X`

X = false
~X -> true, thus does not equal `X`

X = true
~X -> false, thus does not equal `X`

X = 1+2
~X -> still false, because Boolean of 3 is true, and not true is false

So, is this even possible? Can an such a thing exist? Or is it logically impossible? I would greatly appreciate any possible solutions for this. Thanks in advance for any explanation or insights!

Note: if you think this is completely off-topic and should be removed, I'll ask somewhere else and delete this post. You can just tell me through the comments. However, I still hope that philosophers here can provide some ideas here!

In Boolean algebra, the equation x = ¬ x has no solutions. In other logics, such as 3-valued logics of   Łukasiewicz, Kleene or Priest, the third truth value U (for Unknown) solves it, U = ¬ U. The negation of the unknown is still the unknown.

In philosophy of logic and language you can search for a famous liar sentence regarding such possibility or impossibility or its potential remedy…

To add to @Conifold 's example: Any closed unary operation on a singleton set must be idempotent.,  ie it will trivially satisfy your property. In Python such a type is NoneType. Whether the ~ operation behaves so in Python idk. Will need to check. Python is very laissez-faire wrt type correctness. [ Because programming language creators are invariably self congratulatory towards their babies, they call it dynamic typing! ]

Why asking here about Python?

Note: ‘~’ is a Python operator for bitwise negation. And for ‘~’, creating a situation where ~x == x should be trivial enough. (Obviously it needs to be == not = !) Is that what you want? not is similar looking to ‘~’ but semantically different. So its not clear what you want

I second @MauroALLEGRANZA. As I said above it's easy enough in Python to give you ~x == x. But I cant see why that's philosophy!

@Rushi I wrote it in two forms, X = ~X and X == not X. The first form is intended for non-programmers, and the second is the syntactically correct version written in Python. So, I'm just trying to let everyone here understand what I'm talking about, not just programmers. It seems like there are quite a lot of people on this site who are programmers and experienced  stackoverflow users, but not all of them, this is the philosophy stack exchange after all. So, thanks for your consideration, but I just wrote the first form to let non-programmers understand what I'm saying.

In which case you should write the first as X = ¬X. As I pointed out '~' is more Python than math

Why do you take 0 as false?
If you take -1=false, 1=true, not X = -X, then not 0 = 0.
Similarly, if you take 0 = false as you suggested and 1 = true, and not X = 1-X, then not (1/2) = 1/2.
You can take as negation any involution and then negation of its fixed point will not change its value. For instance, if truth is 5 and falso is 1/5, and not X = 1/X then not 1 = 1.
A more complicated example: if not X = Sqrt(1-X^2) then not (Sqrt(2)/2)=Sqrt(2)/2.

From me +1. The OP however seems confused whether they want math or programming

Nonsense answer to a nonsense question.
